# Ask questions in first or second person?

Tags: questions

When I ask a question, should I use first or second person?
As an example, should I say "How do you do that?" or "How do I do that?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People do things in different ways, and the answer to "How do you do this?" might be different from "How do I do this?".

For example if you asked an international weightlifter "How do you lift those weights?" he might say "I get a good grip, focus on the weight and lift.". If you asked "How do I lift those weights?" he would say "You can't, unless you do strength training for many years."

So you ask the one you want to know the answer to. If you are sure there is no difference between how you might do the thing, and how someone else might do the thing, use either.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the question and what you really want to know.  If you've just watched a magician do a trick, and you ask "How do you do that?" then you're really asking the magician to reveal the secret behind his trick.  If your digital watch is dead and you call the store where you bought it, they may tell you to change the battery.  If you then ask "How do you do that?", you're using the second-person indeterminant, and you really mean "How does anyone do that?" or equivalently "How is that done?"

If you're in Manhattan, and you ask someone how to get to East Hampton, you may get the instruction to take the Long Island Expressway.  Now, if you ask, "How do I do that?" you're asking for yourself.